# Saber si un correo existe o no en Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, dns

Estoy haciendo un API que recibe un JSON con varia informacion de personas, dentro de esos un correo, yo necesito validar si el correo tiene el formato correcto, si el dominio es correcto y si el correcto efectivamente existe en ese dominio.

Este es el codigo que actualmente tengo y me dice si existe el dominio y si esta bien escrito pero necesito saber si ese correo existe tambien!!

AYUDA!!

```
const dns = require('dns');
function Validar_email(email){
  let domain = email.split('@')[1];  
      dns.resolve(domain, 'MX', function(err, addresses) {    
       if (err) {
          console.log("Error")
          console.log(err)    
      } else if (addresses && addresses.length > 0) {      
         console.log("Correcto")
      }
        })
      }
```

Comment: Hola, ya has probado con la función: dns.resolveMx(hostname, callback)

Comment: Disculpa @diegoorellana estuve leyendo al respecto mas no entendi como funciona

Comment: Mailgun tiene una solución para eso: https://www.mailgun.com/email-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te cuento mi experiencia de trabajo, con 2 soluciones:

**SOLUCIÓN 1**

Para validar si un correo existe, lo que he realizado es enviarle un correo de confirmación al cliente correspondiente, dicha confirmación tiene un período de tiempo, por lo cual puede suceder dos cosas:

1. **Si el cliente confirma en el período del tiempo**: Actualiza la información correspondiente en base de datos.
2. **Si el cliente no confirma**: Elimino todos los registros en relación del cliente (Debido que no existe dicho correo), cabe mencionar que la eliminación consta en una bandera de estado la cual lo asigno con valor true (Eliminado).

**SOLUCION 2**

Sin embargo existe servicios de mensajería (Como por ejemplo: SendGrid), la cual contiene un API integrada, en la cual se puede implementar la siguiente solución:

1. Envía un correo a partir del host que te brinda el servicio (Cabe mencionar que cada correo estará identificado por un identificador único).
2. Posteriormente, puedes consultar el API  del servicio de mensajería, y verificar el estado del correo (Entre ellas se puede estar: Enviando, Enviado, recibido, leído, entre otro más...).

---

OJO: En ambas soluciones se debe enviar un correo.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces no existe alguna manera de hacerlo por codigo?

Comment: Del lado del código, solo puedes validar si un correo se envió al servidor del correo, pero sin embargo debes tomar en cuenta que del lado del servidor de correo puede suceder muchas cosas, como por ejemplo: El correo no existe, el correo esta lleno, entre otro más...

Comment: Cabe mencionar que en la segunda solución puedes implementarlo del lado de código, pero debes hacer un Request constante al API del servicio de mensajería, hasta que llegue al estado de recibido.... (Sin embargo, no lo recomiendo, debido que cada consulta al API, tiene un costo).

Comment: Entiendo... muchas gracias por la informacion!

Answer (score -1):

Mailgun tiene una solución para eso: https://www.mailgun.com/email-validation . Además provee un módulo llamado `mailgun-js` con el que puedes validar la dirección fácilmente. Para utilizarlo debes abrir una cuenta en Mailgun. Allí obtendrás una api key y un dominio para inicializar el módulo.

```
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

mailgun.validate('test@mail.com', function (err, body) {
  if(body && body.is_valid){
    // Si llegas aquí todo salió bien y el correo es válido
  }
});
```

Comment: respuestas que son solo enlaces generalmente se toman de baja calidad; se agradece tu ayuda pero revisa [answer]y de paso checa el [tour]